# Obtaining information from a Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with thousands of postcodes in it that has a second column in showing a level (between red, blue and yellow).
I have successfully added the database and can contect to it but the information returned only shows the first line of the database.

my form is pretty basic:-

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="database.php">
  Postcode
  : 
  <input name="postcode" type="text" id="postcode" size="30"><?php echo $postcode ?>
  <br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
```

My php code so far is:-

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","###","###"); 
if (!$con) { 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

mysql_select_db("###", $con); 



$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` LIMIT 0, 33546 ") 
or die(mysql_error());  



$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
// Print out the contents of the entry 

echo "Postcode: ".$row['postcode'];
echo "Level: ".$row['level'];
echo "Floodlevel: ".$row['floodlevel'];


if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) { 
die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
?>
```

I am looking to enter a post code and if the post code is on the database, then the level displayed along with the post code.  If the post code is no in the database, to echo a message saying postcode not listed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you're just diving into the PHP/Mysql world use `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions to get data from database. Avoid using `mysql_` functions as they are obsolete. As for the solution to your problem - @Husman is right :)

Comment: Also remove the LIMIT, it shouldn't be hardcoded, as your database is likely to change in size. Also, is it a good idea to display 33546 rows to the user on one page?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning one row, you need to loop over your results and display them all.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Postcode: ".$row['postcode'];
    echo "Level: ".$row['level'];
    echo "Floodlevel: ".$row['floodlevel'];
}
```

Also, the mysql* functions are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO as described in [the PHP docs](http://php.net/mysql_query)

---

To display a message if the users postcode exists:

```
$postcode = "E9 7TR";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE postcode='$postcode' ") 
or die(mysql_error());  

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
if(mysql_num_rows($row) >= 1) // display success message
else // display not found
```

Again, this is using the old style mysql* queries which are no longer recommended, you are better off using PDO style statements.

Comment: I am not looking to diplay all the post codes.  The user should enter their post code and submit the post code to check if their post code is listed on the data base.  If the post code is not listed it should return a message saying not listed. If it is listed it should display the level.

Comment: In which case your MySQL statement needs to be rewritten. See my updated code.

Comment: Hi Husman thanks for your help so far... I have changed the code to the following $postcode = "E9 7TR"; $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) AS results FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE postcode=$'$postcode' ") or die(mysql_error()); $row = mysql_fetch_array($result ); if($row['results'] >= 1) { echo "Postcode: ".$row['postcode']; echo "Level: ".$row['level']; echo "Floodlevel: ".$row['floodlevel']; } // display success message else { echo "The postcode entered is not listed on the database"; } // but get the following error? You have an error in your SQL syntax;// syntax to use near ''E9 7TR'' at line 1

Comment: I have edited the sql (the old one had two $ in there, which was a typo on my part, sorry)  and I have changed some of the PHP, try that out.

Comment: $postcode = "E9 7TR";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE postcode='$postcode' ") 
or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
if(mysql_num_rows($row) >= 1)
 {
 echo "Postcode: ".$row['postcode'];
 echo "Level: ".$row['level'];
 echo "Floodlevel: ".$row['floodlevel'];
 }
// display success message
else {
 echo "The postcode entered is not listed on the database";
}
?>